# How to read ms access database file programmatically without installing ms office in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have created an application which reads ms access database file (test.accdb).

When i tested the application in my pc it worked fine.

But when i tried to run my application in different pc without installing ms office 2007 it does not read my database.

later when i installed ms office 2007 it worked for me.

Some people dont have ms office may be some people dont know about ms office. If they dont have ms office they need to download it from website which is more than 500 mb. Everyone Cant download it because its very big.they could have limited internet.

I want to read the database file without installing ms office 2007 in client pc.

Is there any code from which we can read it.

There would be great appreciation if someone could help me.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1688522/100283

Comment: It's also quite expensive **to buy** and distributing it like you're describing is **illegal**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft Access required for C# database access on end-user machines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688468/microsoft-access-required-for-c-sharp-database-access-on-end-user-machines)

Comment: I am using these connection string            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\\test.accdb";Persist Security Info=True");

Comment: If you have users that don't have MS Office, maybe you shouldn't be using MS Access as a database format.

Comment: SQLite, SQL Server Express -- both better than Access, both free...

Comment: @AustinSalonen SQL Server Compact would probably be a better choice than Express.

Comment: For the last 10+ years (and even win98SE) all versions of windows have shipped with the JET data engine. You NEVER needed Access installed to open and read mdb files. For Access 2007/2010 data formats there is a new data engine (including a 64 bit edition). For  2007/2010 accDB file then you need to install the ACE engine which is not part of windows install like JET was. This engine is free. Ignore the comments here from people who do not understand the difference between MS Access and what a database engine is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you connect to the database? You should be able to ODBC into it. You will need to install the [ODBC](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23734) driver on the client machines though.

Comment: Just the connection string probably if you're not already using ODBC.