# How can I use a MS-Access DB in a computer without Access installed?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am new to `MS-access`, I developed a web application which use's **MS-access** as DB. If i installed my web application in my client system is it necessary to install **MS-access** in my client System too. Is it any other way to use **MS-Access without installing** it?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246134/how-to-read-ms-access-database-file-programmatically-without-installing-ms-offic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html). which access MS Access with configuring ODBC drive.

For More detail .refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc)

Answer (score 2):

You need what is called Access Runtime Version.  It is a free app from Microsoft that will allow end users to run Access databases without purchasing Access.

The link to the 2007 version is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4438).  If you need a different version, just Google "Access Runtime Version".