# Windows form using access database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2007, connection-string

I am using MS ACCESS database for my windows application. In development PC I have install Microsoft Access Database Engine. Do I need to install this on the PCs where I will be installing this windows form application. If not what is the solution to this so that my application can interact with the database like is there any dlls or anything such that need to be included in the application's reference. My database is in .accdb format not .mdb

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8246134/3436942) question might help

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8302349/1997232).

Answer (score 0):

For your program to interact with the Microsoft Access DB, you would have to create the DB in .accdb first. Once that is done, goto

> Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Data Sources(ODBC)->System DSN.

Here select Microsoft Access Driver(*.accdb, *.mdb).A pop up window opens. There first give a name to your file.

> Remember to use this name in your code to access your MS Accesss DB

Then click Add to navigate and add your .accdb file and click OK. Now your DB is live for you in local system for you to use.