# Can I use pyodbc or anything similar without having MS Access installed on my computer?

Tags: python, ms-access, driver, pyodbc

Can I open a *.mdb Access database to display the table rows (in cmd for example) if I haven't installed Microsoft Access on my computer?

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688468/microsoft-access-required-for-c-sharp-database-access-on-end-user-machines/1688522#1688522 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246134/how-to-read-ms-access-database-file-programmatically-without-installing-ms-offic and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc

Comment: For pyodbc, you could try using 32-bit Python and `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}`. Or you could use a general-purpose database tool like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io) to access the file.

Comment: @June7 Thanks but most of microsoft external links are broken.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I installed [Access database engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=54920).

Because i have python 64 bit, with MS Office without MS Access, i installed first the 32 bit version and then the 64 version with `/quiet` flag from cmd.

After that i can use the *.mdb files with `pyodbc` python module.